# Unable to load the store in redux with some static data

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

I am trying to develop a web app using react, redux and webpack.
I am getting error while trying to load the store in redux with some static data.

Please see the error below[image: error image]

Can someone please help me solve the error.

I have looked for similar question on stack overflow but the solution that they provided is what I already have in my application.
Like people asked to include dependencies and make some changes in presets

Please see my code below:
    app.jsx:

```
    store.dispatch(actions.changeDirection('Right', true));

    store.dispatch(actions.addTitle());

    var pages1 = [
    {'1',
     'slide1SubHeading1',
     ['point1', 'point2', 'point3']},
     {'2', 'slide1SubHeading2', ['point1', 'point2', 'point3']}
     ];

     var pages2 = [
     {'1', 'slide2SubHeading1', ['point1', 'point2', 'point3']},
     {'2', 'slide2SubHeading2', ['point1', 'point2', 'point3']}
     ];

     var pages3 = [
     {'1', 'slide3SubHeading1', ['point1', 'point2', 'point3']},
     {'2', 'slide3SubHeading2', ['point1', 'point2', 'point3']}
     ];

     store.dispatch(actions.addSlide('ReactSlide 1', false, true, pages1));
     store.dispatch(actions.addSlide('ReactSlide 2', true, true, pages2));
     store.dispatch(actions.addSlide('ReactSlide 3', true, false, pages3));
```

module in webpack.config.js:

```
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
            },
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
          }
        ]
    }
```

dependencies:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.9.1",
        "express": "^4.13.4",
        "firebase": "^3.0.2",
        "react": "^0.14.7",
        "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
        "react-router": "^2.0.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
        "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "deep-freeze-strict": "^1.1.1",
        "expect": "^1.14.0",
        "foundation-sites": "6.2.0",
        "jquery": "^2.2.1",
        "moment": "^2.12.0",
        "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
        "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.6",
        "react-redux": "^4.4.1",
        "redux": "^3.3.1",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.0.3",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
        "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "script-loader": "^0.6.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
        "webpack": "^1.12.13",
        "node-env-file": "^0.1.8"
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do something like this

```
var pages1 = [
{'1',
 'slide1SubHeading1',
 ['point1', 'point2', 'point3']}
 //...
 ]
```

You're creating a js array whose first element is the following js object

```
{'1',
 'slide1SubHeading1',
 ['point1', 'point2', 'point3']}
```

However this is no valid js object, since a js object is composed of key and values, here you got only values.

To fix this you have to add key to your object, for instance :

```
var pages1 = [
   {pageNumber: '1',
    heading: 'slide1SubHeading1',
    points: ['point1', 'point2', 'point3']}
    //...
]
```

(I just tried to guess key names from the content, but it's probably not the names you want).